# Can we change what displays in the "How To Format" help box?

Tags: feature-request

On Stack Overflow the "How To Format" box to the left of the Ask Question screen has a few extra helpful hints, such as:

> indent code by 4 spaces

The ExpressionEngine site doesn't have that. I realize it's only useful on sites which revolve around code, but is there any way we can add that particular helpful hint to the EE site?